# Subscript underneath probability

Tags: math-mode, math-operators

I want to write probabilities of the form

[image]

I have a command that looks like this:

```
\newcommand{\prob}[2][]{\mathcmd{\Pr\left[{#2}\if!#1!\else\mid{#1}\fi\right]}}
```

But how can I add the subscript to the probability?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would create separate macros for unconditional and conditional probabilities of events.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mleftright} % for '\mleft' and '\mright' macros
\usepackage{mathtools}  % for '\DeclarePairedDelimiter' macro
\DeclareMathOperator{\negl}{\textsf{negl}}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\abs}{\lvert}{\rvert}
%% Create separarate macros for unconditional and conditional probabilities:
\newcommand\uprob[2][]{\Pr_{#1}\mleft[\,#2\,\mright]}
\newcommand\cprob[3][]{\Pr_{#1}\mleft[\,#2\;\middle\vert\;#3\,\mright]}

\begin{document} 
\[
\abs[\Big]{\,\uprob[x\leftarrow X_\lambda]{\mathcal{A}(1^\lambda,x)=1} 
           - \uprob[y\leftarrow Y_\lambda]{\mathcal{A}(1^\lambda,y)=1}}
\le \negl(\lambda)\,.
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Let's increase the score for everyone you truly deserve it.

Answer (score 4):

You can define a new command, here called `\xPr`.

The syntax is

```
\xPr_{<subscript>}[<size>]{<matherial>}
```

where both `_{<subscript>}` and `[<size>]` are optional. In the mandatory argument there can be a single `|` token for conditional probability.

Here are some examples, compared with the standard syntax.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareMathOperator{\negl}{\mathsf{negl}}

\NewDocumentCommand{\xPr}{ e{_} O{} >{\SplitArgument{1}{|}}m}{%
  \Pr\IfValueT{#1}{_{#1}}
  \xPrCond{#2}#3
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\xPrCond}{mmm}
 {
  \mathopen{#1[} #2 \IfValueT{#3}{\mathrel{#1|}#3} \mathclose{#1]}
 }

\begin{document}

\begin{gather}
% new command
\Bigl|
  \xPr_{x\gets X_\lambda}{A(1^\lambda,x)=1}
  -
  \xPr_{y\gets Y_\lambda}{A(1^\lambda,y)=1}
\Bigr|
\le \negl(\lambda)
\\
% standard
\Bigl|
  \Pr_{x\gets X_\lambda}[A(1^\lambda,x)=1]
  -
  \Pr_{y\gets Y_\lambda}[A(1^\lambda,y)=1]
\Bigr|
\le \negl(\lambda)
\\
% new command
\Bigl|
  \xPr_{x\gets X_\lambda}[\big]{A(1^\lambda,x)=1}
  -
  \xPr_{y\gets Y_\lambda}[\big]{A(1^\lambda,y)=1}
\Bigr|
\le \negl(\lambda)
\\
% standard
\Bigl|
  \Pr_{x\gets X_\lambda}\bigl[A(1^\lambda,x)=1\bigr]
  -
  \Pr_{y\gets Y_\lambda}\bigl[A(1^\lambda,y)=1\bigr]
\Bigr|
\le \negl(\lambda)
\\
% new command
\xPr{A|B}+\xPr[\big]{A|B}+\xPr_{y}[\big]{A|B}
\\
% standard
\Pr[A\mid B]+\Pr\bigl[A\bigm|B\bigr]+\Pr_y\bigl[A\bigm|B\bigr]
\end{gather}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If your LaTeX version is prior to 2020-10-01, you need `\usepackage{xparse}`.